# Sum of XSLT nodes that aren't linked

Tags: xslt, sum, xslt-1.0

> Hi SO,
>
> New to XSLT and have been debugging this code for a while
>
> The current variable is always returning 0
>
> I need to find the sum of all (X) with the same value of (D) through each (Row)
>
> V and W are related, not sure how to "connect" them
>
> Example:

```
Row (AAA123)[SomeDesc1] = 1.00 + 

Row (BBB456)[SomeDesc1] = 3.00 

SumOfSomeDesc1 = 4.00
```

> XSLT 1.0 only

XML:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <ID>AAA123</ID>
    <V>
      <X>1.00</X>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>2.00</X>
    </V>
    <MultipleFieldsInBetween />
    <W>
      <D>SomeDesc1</D>
    </W>
    <W>
      <D>SomeDesc2</D>
    </W>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>BBB456</ID>
    <V>
      <X>3.00</X>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>4.00</X>
    </V>
    <MultipleFieldsInBetween />
    <W>
      <D>SomeDesc1</D>
    </W>
    <W>
      <D>SomeDesc2</D>
    </W>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

XSLT Sum (Current):

```
<xsl:variable name="SumOfX" select="sum(//Row[ID/text()=$ID]/V[D/text()
=$Description])" />
```

Comment: How are `V` and `W` related, by the position, that is the first `V` child of a `Row` belongs to the first `W` child?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Position yes, V[x] W[x], really not sure why it wasn't just one element but I have to use it as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle it as a grouping problem, first identifying unique descriptions, then finding `Row`s by the description and finally summing up the elements in the same position:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="desc-group" match="Row/W/D" use="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="desc-groups" select="//Row/W/D[generate-id() = generate-id(key('desc-group', .)[1])]"/>

    <xsl:key name="row-group" match="Row" use="W/D"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Description</th>
                           <th>Sum</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$desc-groups"/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row/W/D">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(.. | ../preceding-sibling::W)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('row-group', .)/V[position() = $pos]/X)"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Description</th>
               <th>Sum</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>SomeDesc1</td>
               <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>SomeDesc2</td>
               <td>6</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I agree with Martin. Grouping seems like the logical solution to the stated problem.